# cp files with pattern with middle directory variable

Tags: files, cp, mv

I have a directory l

```
── 10020
│   ├── live
│   │   ├── 211231.jpg
│   │   ├── 211231_BB.txt
│   │   ├── 448378.jpg
│   │   ├── 448378_BB.txt
│   │   ├── 460830.jpg
│   │   └── 460830_BB.txt
│   └── spoof
│       ├── 035383.jpg
│       ├── 035383_BB.txt
│       ├── 057847.jpg
│       ├── 057847_BB.txt
│       ├── 080343.jpg
│       ├── 080343_BB.txt
├── 10021
│   ├── live
│   │   ├── 013031.jpg
│   │   ├── 013031_BB.txt
│   │   ├── 025895.jpg
│   │   ├── 025895_BB.txt
│   └── spoof
│       ├── 006434.jpg
│       ├── 006434_BB.txt
│       ├── 021470.jpg
│       ├── 021470_BB.txt
│       ├── 027017.jpg
│       ├── 027017_BB.txt
├── 10022
│   ├── live
│   │   ├── 125401.jpg
│   │   ├── 125401_BB.txt
│   │   ├── 196573.jpg
│   │   └── 196573_BB.txt
│   └── spoof
│       ├── 013054.jpg
│       ├── 013054_BB.txt
│       ├── 015386.jpg
│       ├── 015386_BB.txt
│       ├── 016760.jpg
│       ├── 016760_BB.txt
│       ├── 020204.jpg
│       ├── 020204_BB.txt
├── 10023
│   ├── live
│   │   ├── 000240.jpg
│   │   ├── 000240_BB.txt
│   │   ├── 030384.jpg
│   │   ├── 030384_BB.txt
│   │   ├── 034898.jpg
│   │   ├── 034898_BB.txt
│   └── spoof
│       ├── 022241.jpg
│       ├── 022241_BB.txt
│       ├── 023855.jpg
│       ├── 023855_BB.txt
│       ├── 030252.jpg
│       ├── 030252_BB.txt
│       └── 475104_BB.txt
 [it goes on, as you guys suggested I put up the real directory rather than a simplified version]
```

I want to cp or mv all `*/live/*.jpg` and `*/live/*.png`
into another directory like `dir`
how can I achieve this?

Things I tried:

```
rsync -av ~/train/*/*.jpg dir
find ~train/ -type f -name '*/live/*.jpg' -exec cp '{}' dir ';'
rsync -a --include '*.jpg' --exclude 'live/*' ~/train/ dir
```

Comment: for `find`, use the `-path` or `-ipath` filter.

Comment: The first arg of `find` does not match the dir as stated in the question.

Comment: Do you want to keep the source path at the destination? If not, what's wrong with `cp */real/*.jpeg */real/*.png dir/`?

Comment: @roaima `cp: cannot stat '*/real/*.jpeg': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '*/real/*.png': No such file or directory`

Comment: @Moe don't take roaima's command literally. Try to understand what it means. I would say you have a path problem here. What is the real structure of your directories, would you change your example with a real sample?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I get it but that is exactly what I'm asking :)), also I put some of the directory's tree

Comment: Do you just want to move the files into a single directory, or do you want the copy to retain some of the directory structure?

Comment: @roaima into a single directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw, in this case, there isn't any subdirectory with the name of `real`, so if you share your real directory name, maybe you have a little problem with your keywords.
by the way, you can use "find" with structure @Kusalananda or using a for loop to cp your files and directories

Answer (score 1):

> `find -path '/media/data/woreom/dataset/CelebA_Spoof/Data/train /*/real/*.jpg' -type f -exec cp '{}' /media/data/woreom/dataset/dataset/real/ ';'` does nothing.

This is because you asked to find `/media/data/woreom/datase…` in your current working directory.

You need to specify where to search, as first argument. So change to (I think this should do it.)

```
find /media/data/woreom/dataset/CelebA_Spoof/Data/train \
    -path '/*/real/*.jpg' -type f \
    -exec echo cp '{}' /media/data/woreom/dataset/dataset/real/ ';'
```

I added the word `echo` for testing, remove when it is working porperly.

Comment: this still does nothing :))

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming you adapt it to your directory structure and I understand you correctly.

```
user@user:~$ tree

├── dir
└── foo
    ├── 10021
    │   └── live
    │       ├── a.jpg
    │       ├── b.jpg
    │       ├── c.jpg
    │       └── d.jpg
    ├── 10022
    │   └── live
    │       ├── e.jpg
    │       └── f.jpg
    └── 10023
        └── live
            ├── g.jpg
            ├── h.jpg
            ├── i.jpg
            └── j.jpg
```

Now, placed into you home directory:

```
cp */live/*.{jpg,png} ~/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let the shell do the heavy lifting with globbing wildcards

```
shopt -s nullglob
cp */live/*.jpg */live/*.png dir/
```

The first command tells the `bash` shell not to fail to expand patterns that don't exist but instead to strip them out as non-matches. (For example from your question, here are no `png` files in the `10020/live/` directory; normally that would mean the command would end up seeing the literal `10020/live/*.png` which would fail to match as there is no `png` file with an asterisk as its name.)

If you don't run `bash` you can redirect the *stderr* output of the `cp` command to null (`cp ... 2>/dev/null`) so that you don't see the error messages generated by the invalid failure to expand patterns such as `10020/live/*.png`, but you'll also redirect other error messages too so this should be a last step option.

If you really want a clean solution you could copy the files one by one, but it's less efficient and generally harder to read

```
for file in */live/*.jpg */live/*.png
do
    [ -f "$file" ] && cp "$file" dir/
done
```

You don't really need a trailing slash on `dir/` but I tend to write it that way to make it crystal clear I'm intending `dir` to be a directory. (In the extreme event that you end up copying only one file when `dir` doesn't exist, using `dir/` rather than just `dir` will safely fail by triggering an error instead of silently renaming the file to be `dir`.)

In both cases you can prefix `echo` to the `cp` command to see the command that would be executed without actually changing anyway (i.e. use `echo cp …` instead of just `cp …`)